# Multiple network interface in a pod | OPENSHIFT 3.11

Tags: networking, kubernetes, openshift

I wanted to add an additional network interface to a pod using multus.
I have an openshift version = 3.11 on my host.
But when I was creating a NetworkAttachmentDefinition, it didn't accept it and I got this *error:* **the server doesn't have a resource type "network-attachment-definitions"**

Anyone who have an idea about this ? 
Or an idea about adding additional network interface to a pod using openshift version 3.11 ?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: As far as I know, OpenShift 3.11 does not support multiple NIC interfaces for Pod. As you know, multus CNI is required it for that. But multus is supported as of OCP4. You need to use OCP4 for that.

Comment: Thank you for answering @DaeinPark
I am using OCP 3.11 because it is open source, is it the case for OCP4 ?

Comment: As I check the OKD(Opensource version of the Openshift) release note here https://github.com/openshift/okd/releases, I think you can install OCP4 as Opensource.